# How to convert array into object in and iterate over list in angular 5?

Tags: arrays, json, object, angular5

JSON: I have the json in which I want to iterate userids in list but I am able to fetch userids but not the content in  a list.

```
{
    "data": {
        "items": [
            {
                "regions": "India",
                "ownerids": "[master]",
                "userids": "[\"sia(123), Smith James(124)\"]",
                "groupid": "111",
                "groupname": "Gopi_test1"
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

html: In this I am using userids so that it is printing as "sia(123), Smith James(124)\" but I am facing problem to display as sia and smith james in form of list i.e 
1) sia
2) smith james

```
<li *ngFor= "let member of userids">
<span><input  type="checkbox"/>
 <label>{{member}}</label></span>
</li>



Component:// This is my component and hidden some part of code...
@Component({
  selector: 'app-group',
  templateUrl: './group.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./group.component.css']
})
export class GroupComponent implements OnInit {    
    userids :any[];

     ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getGroupMembers().subscribe(data => {this.userids = data.data.items});
    }
//some part of code is hidden 
}
```

Comment: @connexo: still you find as invalid code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have at least some control over how the data you are receiving is structured. Here are some things that I recommend you change.

1. Try not to combine multiple values into a single string. Keeping them separate will give you more control over how you use the data later on. It will also keep you from having to parse the values unnecessarily
2. Use arrays where multiple values should be grouped together
3. Name your properties accordingly, use plural for arrays and singular for single values

I created a simple demo which will render the list you desire. Perhaps it can serve as an example.

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-52995239-json-structuring)**

Comment: I understood your demo and I agree with you that what you were saying about not to combine multiple values into a single string but we had to maintain "userids" in a single string and we don't have any control to manipulate the api. 

It would be great if you can suggest me the logic or code where we can convert the existing userids value i.e "userids": "[\"sia(123), Smith James(124)\"]" in a convenient way in Angular part so that we can utilize and display in the form of list in html.

Comment: In that case you will have to at least parse the value you are getting. **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-52995239-json-parse)**. To use the same HTML as before you can further process the strings in order to get an object you can work with. **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-52995239-json-parse-regex)**. Personally I like neither approach, they are hacky and will break easily but I hope they help.